# How to get rid of tiny black spots on white plastic cutting board?

Tags: cleaning, cutting-boards

When I looked in the dishwasher this morning after it ran overnight, I noticed an amount of tiny flecks on the white plastic cutting board I have, on both sides of the surface. After taking it to the sink, no amount of scrubbing is getting them out!

-What is it?

-How do I get them out?

-Can I still use it?

Comment: A picture would be very useful.

Comment: @GoD Unfortunately I do not have the means to take one =/

Comment: Without a picture I don't think this is answerable I'm afraid.

Comment: Try bleach ....

Comment: Sounds like mold, but as other said: we need pictures with sufficient detail. Voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*

Comment: Are there knife grooves or other scratches that the spots are in?  If so, it'll be difficult to get out without scraping a think layer off of the cutting board to remove the nooks that things get stuck in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been indicated, pictures would be helpful for this but without one a simple suggestion would be to try bleach. Depending on the size of your board you can submerge the board in a [bleach and water bath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tb3lQgvIrFA) or get a towel (paper or cloth) soaked with bleach and water and set that on top of the spots and let that sit for a while.

Comment: I don't have bleach but I like the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps a crazy and irresponsible idea, but would taking a light touch of a blowtorch to it help?

Comment: Fire would be unlikely to do anything good for your board.

Comment: Please do not use a torch, at best you'll ruin your board, at worst you will get toxic fumes from it.

Comment: @WeckarE. It would smooth out your board but would be very difficult to do well and would probably warp your board too much.